# Heartbleed OpenSSL upgrade issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, openssl, ubuntu-13.04, heartbleed-bug

Ok, so I updated my OpenSSL on my AWS EC2 server (in order to avoid the heartbleedbug) from v1.0.1c to v1.0.1f . I had to compile it from source and install it. I restarted the server , everything works A OK and openssl is showing the latest version that was released on 7 April 2014. So that's all fine and well, however, I have a security certificate from thawte and when I do the vulnerability test from their website tools, they say that I am still vulnerable.

Does this mean I have to reissue and regenerate my key and certificates ? Or is it just a caching issue from their side ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about software versions, administration and patching. Server Fault has quite a few questions on the topic: http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/heartbleed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to reissue your certificates. That's the whole point of patching your vulnerabilities. Recompiling OpenSSL will do you no good unless you are using the `openssl` executable.

Answer (score 0):

why **`1.0.1f`** ?

It should be **`1.0.1g`**. Check this: https://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20140407.txt and http://nginx.com/blog/nginx-and-the-heartbleed-vulnerability/